# Acknowledgement bit setting in CAN lower level

Tags: embedded, embedded-resource, bootloader, can-bus

As we know, in CAN Acknowledgement bit is set when receiver receives the transmitted data correctly.
Can you please explain how this bit is set and who monitors and sets at CAN lower level ?

I am trying to test the below test case :
In which tester is sending high priority frames until maximum timeout for Ar and after this maximum timeout i am getting positive response but ideally we should get no response.
So i am trying to understand who sets the bit for Acknowledgement as I am getting positive response for my test case.

Comment: What timeout are you talking about?

Comment: Ar timing parameter for maximum timeout ie.1000ms

Answer (score 0):

Any node actively participating on the bus will set the ACK bit upon receiving a valid frame. This is done by CAN controller hardware. This is a low level error detection mechanism, not to be confused with higher application-level concepts of identifying which nodes that are present on the bus etc.

> after this maximum timeout i am getting positive response but ideally we should get no response.

That doesn't make any sense. Either you send frames and they get ACK:ed or you don't send frames in which case they don't get ACK:ed.

Comment: How is it taken care in Can Controller hardware layer ?

Comment: @JasmithaMurri What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the ACK is handle by CAN controller (peripheral). If you send a message, any CAN node check and saw that data is correct, it will automatically send the ACK signal event it does not configure to received that message. The only way to ask the controller not send ACK signal is: set to standby or listen only mode.

I'm not clear the condition for expect no response because it is the auto process.